# Returning multiple integers as separate variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, return-value

I am trying to make a program that grabs 5 integers from the user, and then finds the average of them. I have it set up to take in the 5 numbers, but how do I return them all as separate variables so I can use them later on? Thanks!

```
def main():
    x = 0
    testScoreNumber = 1
    while x < 5:
        getNumber_0_100(testScoreNumber)
        x += 1
        testScoreNumber += 1

    calcAverage(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5)

    print(calculatedAverage)

def getNumber_0_100(testnumber):
    test = int(input("Enter test score " + str(testnumber) + ":"))
    testcount = 0
    while testcount < 1:
        test = int(input("Enter test score " + str(testnumber) + ":"))

        if test > 0 or test < 100:
            testcount += 1

    return test
```

^Here is the problem, the everytime this function runs, I want it to return a different value to a different variable. Ex. test1, test2, test3.

```
def calcAverage(_score1,_score2,_score3,_score4,_score5):
    total = _score1 + _score2 + _score3 + _score4 + _score5
    calculatedAverage = total/5

    return calculatedAverage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the result somewhere.  It is usually (always?) a bad idea to dynamically create variable names (although it is possible using `globals`).  The typical place to store the results is in a list or a dictionary -- in this case, I'd use a list.

change this portion of the code:

```
x = 0
testScoreNumber = 1
while x < 5:
    getNumber_0_100(testScoreNumber)
    x += 1
    testScoreNumber += 1
```

to:

```
results = []
for x in range(5):
    results.append( getNumber_0_100(x+1) )
```

which can be condensed even further:

```
results = [ getNumber_0_100(x+1) for x in range(5) ]
```

---

You can then pass that results list to your next function:

```
avg = get_ave(results[0],results[1],...)
print(avg)
```

Or, you can use the unpacking operator for shorthand:

```
avg = get_ave(*results)
print(avg)
```

Comment: +1 for good explanations of all of the steps. (Although "all the numbers from 1 to 5" might better be written as `x for x in range(1, 6)` than `x+1 for x in range(5)`.)

Comment: @abarnert -- Yeah.  I don't know which is better.  I like `range(5)` as it is extremely clear that you'll end up with 5 elements -- and it seemed like a slightly closer translation of OP's code -- but subtracting 1 from 6 isn't too hard either :-)

Comment: I'm not sure which is better either, which is why I wrote "might". I have a friend who used to teach intro programming, and he had the students write a `closed_range` function on their first day, so they could write `closed_range(1, 5)` until they got used to thinking 0-based… I think that might be going a little too far, but hey, I'm not a teacher.

Comment: I teach a class here and there, but it's mostly grad students -- They're typically able to figure stuff like that out :)

Comment: What do I change the parameter of getNumber to? Or does it matter? What changes need to be made to that function? Thanks.

Comment: @user1041950 -- I'm not sure I understand.  That function looks like it will work ...

Comment: @mgilson - You were correct, had a small problem in some other code I added. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the responsibility of the returning function to say what the caller does with its return value. In your case, it would be simple to let main have a list where it adds the return values. You could do this:

```
scores = []
for i in range(5):
    scores.append(getNumber_0_100(i))

calcAverage(*scores)
```

Note that `*scores` is to pass a list as arguments to your calcAverage function. It's probably better to have calculateAverage be a general function which takes a list of values and calculates their average (i.e. doesn't just work on five numbers):

```
def calcAverage(numbers):
    return sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
```

Then you'd call it with just `calcAverage(scores)`

A more Pythonic way to write the first part might be `scores = [getNumber_0_100(i) for i in range(5)]`

Answer (score 0):

Python allows you to return a tuple, and you can unroll this tuple when you receive the return values.  For example:

```
def return_multiple():
    # do something to calculate test1, test2, and test3
    return (test1, test2, test3)

val1, val2, val3 = return_multiple()
```

The limitation here though is that you need to know how many variables you're returning.  If the number of inputs is variable, you're better off using lists.